# Maximization of generalized Rayleigh quotient of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the maximization of generalized Rayleigh quotient of vector $\mathbf{x}$, i.e.,

$$\max_x \frac{x^HAx}{x^HBx}$$
can be achieved with $x$ being the largest eigenvector of $B^{-1}A$.

But how about when $x$ becomes a matrix? i.e., for the following problem,

$$\max_X \mathrm{tr}(X^HAX(X^HBX)^{-1})$$

is the optimal $X$ being the combination of the largest $n$ eigenvalues?
(Maybe a constraints liek $X^HX=I$ is required)?

Comment: Additional constraint $X^H X = I$ effectively reduces the problem to $\operatorname{tr} (X^H A X (X^H B X)^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr} (X^H A X X^H B^{-1} X) = \operatorname{tr} (X^H A B^{-1} X) = \operatorname{tr} (X X^H A B^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr} (A B^{-1}) = \operatorname{const}$

Comment: @uranix That only holds if $X$ is a square matrix. In general, $X^HX = I$ only implies that $X$ has orthonormal columns

Comment: @Lin An easier problem to solve here would be 
$$
\max_X \frac{\operatorname{tr}(X^HAX)}{\operatorname{tr}(X^HBX)}.
$$